# Programmatically logout a user in Pusher presence channel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, websocket, pusher

I have a Rails api only app and two FE clients.

I want to use a presence channel to understand which users in client A are currently in a single page and show it in real time in client B.
When the user in A visits that page I have an API call, and inside that API I put

```
Pusher.trigger("presence-live-event-1", 'start', user_id: current_user.id)
```

When the user leaves, how can I send a "logout" event?

To prove it working, when you do `Pusher.get('/channels/presence-live-event-1/users')` you should have zero users connected

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer given by QA team.

There is no requirement to manually update the presence information with your own event being triggered. Presence channels automatically update as users join or leave the channel. See [member-added](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels#pusher-member-added) and [member-removed](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels#pusher-member-removed) for details.

In my case I will unsubscribe from presence channel at FE.